# Javascript: IF function including value over and radiobutton check

Tags: javascript

I have this variable "Age" which is textbox (number) and other variables which are checboxes (variable1,variable2 and variable3).

I want to put a specific instructions what happens when age is under 60 and Dysuria and Pollakisuria are checked "yes" and Fever 3 is checked "no".

I can manage to do this without age parameter with this code:

html:

```
Age; <input id="age" name="age" size="2" style="height: 22px; width: 47px" type="number" /><br />
Dysuria : <input id="dysuria1" name="dysuria" type="radio" value=", dysuria" />Yes <input id="dysuria2" name="dysuria" type="radio" value="" />No<br />
Pollakisuria : <input id="pollakisuria1" name="pollakisuria" type="radio" value=", pollakisuria" />Yes <input id="pollakisuria2" name="pollakisuria" type="radio" value="" />No<br />
Fever : <input id="fever1" name="fever" type="radio" value=", fever" />Yes <input id="fever2" name="fever" type="radio" value="" />No<br />
<button id="buttonuri">Button</button>
<p><textarea cols="10" id="uri" name="uri" rows="1" style="height: 80px; width:473px"></textarea></p>
                        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script></td><td></textarea></p>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("#buttonuri").bind('click',function(){
  if(($('#pollakisuria1').is(':checked'))&& 
    ($('#dysuria1').is(':checked'))&& ($("#fever2").is(':checked'))){ 
     $('#uri').val('text here') } else { ($('#uri').val('Other text 
     here')) 
  }; 
});
```

But how can i include the parameter if age is under 60 and dyrusria&pollakisuria yes & fever no.

Comment: First, try to get the input with id="age" value with your jQuery and/or JavaScript code. Once you have done that you can proceed to utilize that age value in the conditional logic that you are trying to implement. Search other SO entries for how yo do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `$('#age').val()<=60` in If condition

```
    $("#buttonuri").on('click',function(){
  if(($('#age').val() <=60 ) && $('#pollakisuria1').is(':checked') && 
    $('#dysuria1').is(':checked') && $("#fever2").is(':checked')){ 
     $('#uri').val('text here') 
     } else { 
     $('#uri').val('Other text here'); 
  }; 
});
```

[image: Text here case]

[image: Other text here case]

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/jktjgsgL/1/)**

Comment: kindly check your answer .you entered `>=60` but in the snippet is `<=60` ..which one ?

Comment: Thank you  @prasad

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I can´t get that work however :/ Here in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/asfadasda/jktjgsgL/

Comment: There are few errors in your fiddle code. I've updated Fiddle in the answer. Please check. https://jsfiddle.net/saidulu401/jktjgsgL/1/

Comment: @JohnDou Please mark it as a correct so that it will be useful for other users